# InstallAnywhere 2009 hangs with NullPointerException at com.zerog.ia.installer.InstallBundle.shouldRegister(DashoA10*..)

Tags: installanywhere

Using InstallAnywhere 2009 SP2 (version 10.0), during installation it hangs at the beginning of the `Install` phase and displays the following NullPointerException (NPE) in the debug console window:

```
InstallAnywhere 2009
Version: 10.0
__________________________________________________________________________

...

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.InstallBundle.shouldRegister(DashoA10*..)
    at ZeroGbu.a(DashoA10*..)
    at ZeroGbu.a(DashoA10*..)
    at ZeroGbu.b(DashoA10*..)
    at ZeroGbu.a(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.IAStatusLog.setInstallWasStarted(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.Installer.install(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.InstallProgressAction.n(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.ProgressPanelAction$1.run(DashoA10*..)
```

Although installation hangs, the user is able to cleanly stop installation by hitting `Cancel` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CAUSE:**

This issue was caused during the `Pre Install` phase by attempting to set a variable named: `$CHOSEN_INSTALL_SET$`, which is apparently a reserved IA system variable.

Although attempting to set the value of `$CHOSEN_INSTALL_SET$` does not actually change its value, it did trigger a change in other `JAVA_` system variables shown below.

**Variables BEFORE attempted set of $CHOSEN_INSTALL_SET$**

```
JAVA_DOT_HOME=$USER_INSTALL_DIR$$/$jre
JAVA_EXECUTABLE=C:\Program Files\CNMS-NG\jre\bin\java.exe
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\CNMS-NG\jre
```

**Variables AFTER attempted set of $CHOSEN_INSTALL_SET$**

```
JAVA_DOT_HOME=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\I1486584916\Windows\resource\jre
JAVA_EXECUTABLE=
JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\I1486584916\Windows\resource\jre
```

**RESOLUTION:**

Do NOT attempt to manually set a value for variable `$CHOSEN_INSTALL_SET$`
...bad things will happen if you do!!